# malloc error -[CFString release]

Tags: iphone

For some reason my app was crashing on a particular action. After investigation, I found out it is because of releasing something that has already been released. Then I read on the internet that I can track down the cause of this using NSZombie and MallocStackLogging which I implemented and got this as the result.

> NSZombie: 2011-01-19 14:39:09.523
>   iota[13649:207] *** -[CFString
>   release]: message sent to deallocated
>   instance 0xeeaf510
>
> malloc_history
>
> ALLOC 0xeeaf510-0xeeaf52f [size=32]:
>   thread_a0041500 |start | main |
>   UIApplicationMain | GSEventRun |
>   GSEventRunModal | CFRunLoopRunInMode |
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific | **CFRunLoopRun
>   | __CFRunLoopDoTimer |
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION**
>   | __NSFireDelayedPerform |
>   -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtIndexPath:] | -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:]
>   | -[CorpDirViewController
>   tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] |
>   -[CorpDirPersonViewController corpDirViewController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingContact:]
>   | -[ContactItem mergeWithContact:] |
>   -[ContactItem getValueForProperty:] | ABRecordCopyValue |
>   CPRecordCopyProperty |
>   CPRecordGetProperty |
>   ABCMultiValueLoad |
>   ABCDBContextFetchMultiValuePropertyIntoRecord
>   | ABCDBContextFetchMultiValueEntries |
>   CPSqliteStatementSendResults |
>   CollectMultiValueEntries |
>   _sqliteStatementApplyValuesFromRecordWithNullValue
>   | CFStringCreateWithCString |
>   __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 | _CFRuntimeCreateInstance | malloc_zone_malloc

Now I am unable to find out particularly what is causing the crash. Can anyone help me out with it?

Comment: Please format the question into a readable state :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify your alloc/ release on that string. Numbers of alloc+retain must be equal to numbers of release. 
Do not release an autorelease object.

Comment: You must release an autoreleased object if you have retained it before.

Comment: I noticed this issue was occurring from a NSString that was assigned in the header file. After changing to nonatomic everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, you are calling `release` on an object that is already destroyed. That is, you've called `release` one time too many on the object (in this case an NSString). The exception done via NSZombieEnabled now tells you where the "one time too many" release is done. But most of the time you are searching for the release in between, and that is harder to do...

Now that you know where it is crashing (and should thus know which variable is involved) you need to read through your code where you're also releasing this variable or how objects get assigned to that variable and then inspect those sources. That is, you need to "backtrack" where the object originated from and what you've done with it. Somewhere along its life you either forgot to `retain` it, or you accidentially `release`/`autorelease`d it where you shouldn't.

Comment: but we never explicitly release an NSString object. What does the -[CFString release] mean here?

Comment: `CFString` is the underlying class of NSString. You *do* release an NSString, the exception proves it ;-) Now you need to find out where...