# Is there a method that always gets called right after didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopover

I'm working on an iPad app in which I have a table view.  When the user selects a row in the table, I use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to open a popover.  I'm getting an error message saying "message sent to deallocated instance" when I try to use a certain button.  I originally though the errors was getting thrown by the popover (in it's `viewDidLoad` or something), so I put a breakpoint in and stepped through the code.  To my surprise, I was able to step all the way through the loading of the popover and the rest of the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` on my table view (which actually just involves stepping out of some if blocks).  The error then gets thrown when I get a couple steps into the automatically generated code that doesn't appear in any of my class files (that looks like `0x0010d71d <+1164> mov 0x6...`).

So, my question is, how do I find where this error is being thrown?  Is there another method that is automatically run after `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` that could be getting messed up somewhere?

Comment: Does it tell you which message and which class the instance belongs to?

Comment: are you using `autorelease` when you alloc the popover?

Comment: @Phillip Mills: it's saying -[CFString release].  I never use a CFString explicitly myself, so it must be from something else. Maybe I'll google it and see if I find anything helpful.

Comment: @jere: I'm using `performSegueWithIdentifier`and `-(void) prepareForSegue` to show my popover, and the controller is a `@property` of my view controller, so I think that means it should be autoreleased, correct?  I'm pretty new to working with Macs, so a lot of this stuff is still a bit over my head.  Most of what I have is copied from tutorials I've found on SO and youtube, but I don't usually know why it's set up that way, and some of the concepts are still a little fuzzy to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, everyone's responses lead me to find [malloc error -[CFString release]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734251/malloc-error-cfstring-release), which helped me figure out I had a string in my popover that I alloc in `viewDidLoad` by

```
myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[myGlobalFunctionClass getMyString]];
```

Since I alloc it this way, it gets set to autorelease.  The problem was I was explicitly `[myString release];` and `myString = nil;` in `viewWillAppear`.  Removing the `release` and `=nil` parts cleaned up my error.

To answer the actual question that I posted, I believe the `autorelease` wasn't firing until the simulator actually tried to display the popover (which would run after `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`).  Since that occurs after I explicitly `[myString release]` in `viewWillAppear`, it was trying to `autorelease` something that was no longer there.  Just to reiterate, the proper way to do it was let it `autorelease` at the end, and not `[myString release]` anywhere in my code.

Can someone verify that this is correct?  As I mentioned in my comments, I'm still very new to iOS development.  I have a feeling at the end of this project, I'm going to be able to go back to first stuff I did in it and make dozens of improvements in terms of doing things more efficiently and more in accordance with best practice.

Comment: Yes, [myString release] is a huge no-no on an auto-released object.  Upgrade to ARC, there is a WWDC 2011 video on what ARC is an how to update your project.

Answer (score 1):

Enable NSZombieEnabled in your DEBUG build (see [How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-up-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4)) to locate instances of objects you're accessing that have been deallocated/released.

Also, consider upgrading your project to ARC, which will likely resolve memory management issues like this.

Comment: I have NSZombieEnabled already, and when I do an Analyze the only things I'm getting are a bunch of "value stored during its initialization is never read" on the cells in my popover (which is also built from a UITableViewController).  I'm not familiar with this message, so I'm looking it up now, to see if that's something helpful.

Comment: Edit: it's not on the cells in my popover, it's on the cells in my original view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: So right now in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have: 
`static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
MyCell *cell = (MyCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = [[[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
//plus some stuff about setting labels from an array for indexPath.row`
From what I gather, I'm doing an alloc for `cell` twice.  This part I pretty much copied straight from a tutorial, so not really sure exactly what it does, or which one I need to get rid of, or how to fix it.